# Why is the movie named "The King of Staten Island"?

Tags: title, the-king-of-staten-island

The movie is about a young man. His mom starts dating a firefighter, like his dad who passed away. He has to fix his life.

Why is the movie named "[The King of Staten Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_King_of_Staten_Island)"?

Comment: I haven't seen the film, but a quick glance at Wiki tells me that there is a character that rides the Staten Island Ferry to Manhatten to take the "civil service exam". They have a romantic moment. I surmise that this is something the main character wanted badly, to be with this other character...

Comment: Being a civil servant is a path to being a political figure, so one could argue that even Kings/Queens of other countries are types of political figures, despite the US doesn't have Monarchist government. So if the main character who has been running around Staten Island with his love interest who has political pursuits finally professes his love, then he is "comedically" her King

Answer (score -3):

Other films with similar titles about figurative royalty include:

*Prince of Foxes* (1949).

*Prince  of Players* (1955).

*King of Hearts* (1966).

*The King of Marvin Gardens* (1972).

*Emperor of The North Pole* (1973).

*The Prince of Central Park* (1977).

*Prince of the City* (1981).

*The King of Comedy* (1982).

*Prince of Pennsylvania* (1988).

*King of New York* (1990).

*Emperor of the Bronx* (1990).

*The Prince of Tides* (1991).

*Robin Hood: Prince of Thieves* (1991).

*King of the Hill* (1993).

*The Prince of Central Park* (2000).

Etc.

So it is quite common for movie titles to describe someone as figurative and not literal royalty.  And possibly some of those movies at titled for the same reason as *King of Staten Island* is.